# Google Webmasters, getting blank errors?

Tags: google-search-console

I've been getting blank errors in the Search Appearance -> Structured Data section of Google Webmasters.  Here's a screenshot of the errors, clicking on them to show the details doesn't give anymore information.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Update

Here are some more screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a good one! I wish I knew...

Comment: It is a bit slow here this weekend. I want you to have an answer so I made sure I up-voted to hopefully get your question some attention.

Comment: That doesn't look like errors to me. please can you repost another screen shot without cropping the top. I suspect you have corrected the errors and you are looking at the top graph which displays historic error information, however current information will not display errors if the problem has been resolved. Please edit your question and include more information as answers at present would be guesses which could either be false or true.

Comment: If you take a look at https://www.bybe.net/stackexchange/webmasters/webmaster-tools-schema-no-errors.png there is no errors, however at the top it still reported those errors for some time. Errors should look like this: https://www.bybe.net/stackexchange/webmasters/webmaster-tools-with-errors.png notice the (!) bubbles, something you screen doesn't have which would imply there is no error.

Comment: @BYBE Thanks!  I included a few more screen shots but I think you already answered my question.  I had a ton of errors that I fixed a while ago and google is slowly re-crawling the site.  I thought it was finding new errors but it sounds like they're just showing them as cleared?  Seems like they should just remove them from the list.  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Yep, they look like they are clearing up. Damn hentry... I have the same problem, but cba to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to BYBE for this answer.  What I was seeing weren't errors.  After Google clears the errors they remain on the list as items but the error is replaced with a "-" and the exclamation mark is removed, see the example images below.

From BYBE's comment:

If you take a look at this, there are no errors:

[image]

however at the top it still reported those errors for some time. Errors should look like this, notice the (!) bubbles:

[image]

Comment: Yep. The report shows all URLs with structured data, so if you're not seeing errors listed for individual URLs, that's because the markup is fine :).